# Workflow Foundation: Error when resuming a persistent workflow after activity changes

Tags: android-activity, workflow-foundation

the context of the problem is like this: we create workflows, we save it and after a while a new implementation request comes and we change an activity. After this the workflow instances that were saved cannot run anymore. We get this error:

StateMachine Error : Cannot convert object 'True' to type 'System.String'.

It seems that the new argument added brakes the serialization order?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement Dynamic Update in some fashion.

We are currently in the process of getting some infrastructure set up to update existing instances, and having lots of issues.  Hopefully your scenario is easier to solve than ours!

Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314052(v=vs.110).aspx

Word of caution: I've found various issues with Microsoft's provided code that required a lot of investigation to fix.